# Рекурсивно сложить значения массива

Tags: алгоритм, php

Есть массив:

```
$arr = array(21,2,3,5,6);
```

Нужно как-то из него получить:

```
$arr = array(21,23,26,31,37);
```

Т.е. каждое значение сложить с предидущим (естественно кроме 1-го). Подскажите, как можно реализовать данную задачу с наименьшими "извращениями"?

P.S. без `foreach()` и без `count()`.

P.P.S. ключи массива начинаются с 1 на входе, такими же должны быть и на выходе.

Comment: А рекурсивно-то причем здесь ?

Comment: ну как при чем. пробегаемся по всем элементам массива и каждый элемент увеличиваем на значение предыдущего, мне кажется логично... Или я все-же (как и писал) не понимаю толком "назначение" рекурсии.

Comment: Рекурсия требует много ресурсов, лучше использовать итерации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array(0, 21, 2, 3, 5, 6);
$i = 1;while(isset($arr[$i])){
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$i] + $arr[$i-1];
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: Как всегда коротко и ясно )) Спасибо!

Comment: только это не рекурсия....

Comment: А рекурсия тут оказалась и не нужна...

Comment: Это булыжник в огород ТС)

Comment: это называется "рекуррентные формулы".

Answer (score 1):

Что вы скажете насчет такой идеи:

```
$arr = array(1=>21, 2, 3, 5, 6);
mult($arr, $newArr);
print_r($newArr);

function mult(&$oldArray, &$newArray, &$prev = 0) {
    $last = array_pop($oldArray);
    if(empty($oldArray)) {
        $prev = $last;
        $newArray = array(1=>$prev);
        return;
    }
    mult($oldArray, $newArray, $prev);
    $prev = $prev + $last;
    array_push($newArray, $prev);
}
```

Вероятно его можно еще упростить. Плюс ко всему не в курсе как он поведет себя с не числовыми ключами. И, также я совершенно не гарантирую, что алгоритм куда быстрее `foreach`. Но вы просили рекурсию. Хотя насчет отсутствия извращений, я бы не сказал.

Еще есть вариант без рекурсии:

```
function mult2($oldArray) {
    $elem = current($oldArray);
    $newArray = array(key($oldArray)=>$elem);
    while($elem = next($oldArray)) {
        $newArray[key($oldArray)] = $elem + end($newArray);
    }
    return $newArray;
}
$arr = array('a'=>21, 'b'=>2, 1=>3, 5, 6);
```

Причем данный вариант очень хорошо работает с любым типом ключей.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
<?
  function recursive( $arr, $res, $last ) {
      if ( empty($arr) ) return $res;
      $sum = $last + array_pop( $arr );
      $res[] = $sum;
      return recursive( $arr, $res, $sum );
  }

  $arr = array( 21, 2, 3, 5, 6 );
  print_r( $arr );
  $calc = recursive( array_reverse( $arr ), array( 1=> arr[1] ), arr[1] );
  print_r( $calc );
?>
```

либо так ( изменяется исходный массив ):

```
<?
  function recursive( $arr ) {
    $prev = current($arr);
    if ( !next($arr) ) return $arr;
    $arr[ key($arr) ] += $prev;
    return recursive($arr);
  }

  $arr = array( 1=>21, 3, 5, 6 );
  print_r( $arr );
  $calc = recursive( $arr );
  print_r( $calc );
?>
```

либо через итерации:

```
<?
  function iter_while($arr) {
    $prev = current($arr);
    while( next( $arr ) ){
      $arr[ key( $arr ) ] += $prev;
      $prev = current($arr);
    }
    return $arr;
  }

  $arr = array( 1=>21, 3, 5, 6 );
  print_r( $arr );
  $calc = iter_while( $arr );
  print_r( $calc );
?>
```

Comment: Если сделать:

    $arr = array( 1=>21, 2, 3, 5, 6 );

на выходе `print_r( $calc );` будет

> Array ( [0] => 21 [1] => 23 [2] => 26 [3] => 31 [4] => 37 )

вместо

> Array ( [1] => 21 [2] => 23 [3] => 26 [4] => 31 [5] => 37 )

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array(1 => 22, 2=> 3, 3 => 6);
$result[1] = $arr[1];
$totalcount = $arr[1];
for($i = 1; $i < 1000; $i++)
 {
  if (isset($arr[$i +1 ]))
   {
    $result[$i + 1] = $totalcount + $arr[$i + 1];
    $totalcount = $result[$i + 1];
   }
  else
   {
    break;
   }    
 }
print_r($result);
?>
```

Ну вот быстро набросал, наверно, можно получше. Там только массив мой стоит)

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но где тут рекурсия? ))) Код выглядит очень громоздко, мне кажется можно как-то решить с помощью функций array_walk или array_walk_recursive. А вот додуматься что-то не получается...

К тому же использование `$i < 1000;` - не есть хорошо. Вы сразу ограничили количество элементов. А если их 10тыс.... 100тыс.? Понятно, что на практике такого не будет и у меня их будет максимум 31, но все же...

Comment: "Спасибо конечно, но где тут рекурсия? "
В смысле? Ведь он работает нормально.
А, я думал и такие, как array_walk тоже нельзя, раз foreach нельзя. Ну соорудите сами, принцип тот же)

Comment: в том то и дело, ято принцип другой... надо передавать значение по ссылке в вункцию, да еще так, чтоб оно суммировалось с предидущим. А как в функции узнать предидущее значение, если мы в нее будем передавть только значение, а не массив... Это если через array_walk

А если с рекурсией, то тут тупик, проблемы у меня с ней. Сам смысл понимаю, но с кодом проблемы.

Comment: То есть по условию задачи не подходит мой ответ, в смысле надо было обязательно рекурсией?

Comment: Да это не учебное задание. Просто у вас оно слишком громоздко... Допустим если применить foreach все в строку умещается, но на странице этих foreach'ей уже очень много, т.к. это своеобразная страница статистики, собираются разные данные за год, по месяцам, по дням. А как известно, foreach - это самый медленный обход массивов. вот и хочется все переделать по-другому. А с foreach сейчас у меня так:

    foreach ($summ_open as $k=>$v) $summ_open[$k] = $summ_open[$k]+$summ_open[$k-1];

Comment: Строить непойми что вместо одной строки, чтобы один foreach всего не ставить?)

Comment: Я же говорю, что на данной странице таких примеров очень много (но некоторые отличия в порядках сложения по ключам, из-за этого одной функцией не обойтись), потому если оставить один, значит оставить все!

Comment: @DemoS Есть такое решение! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

while(count($arr)>1) $arr[0]+=array_pop($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивно - это так:

```
$a = array(1=>21, 2, 3, 5, 6);
function sum(&$item, $key, &$s){
    $s = $item += $s;
}
array_push($a,$a);
array_walk_recursive($a, 'sum', $s=0);
array_pop($a);
print("a = "); print_r($a);
```

P.S. Есть и более простое решение

```
$a = array(1=>21, 2, 3, 5, 6);
$s=0;
array_walk($a, function (&$item, $key) use(&$s){
    $s = $item += $s;
});
print("a = "); print_r($a);
```

с тем же результатом:
`a = Array ( [1] => 21 [2] => 23 [3] => 26 [4] => 31 [5] => 37 )`