# Выбор из таблицы с сложением

Tags: mysql

Это может быть, так сказать, альтернативный метод решения моей [предыдущей задачи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/49698/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0). Сейчас из таблицы данные тянуться запросом:

```
SELECT day(FROM_UNIXTIME(`t_date`)) as day, COUNT(*) as summ_open FROM table WHERE `t_status`=0 AND month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`t_date`)) = month(now()) GROUP BY day
```

На выходе получаем сумму для каждого дня. Можно ли составить как-то так запрос, чтоб он считал сумму дня и складывал с суммой предидущего дня? Дабы не прибегать к реализации средствами php, а сделать все на mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `simple`
SELECT
  DAY( FROM_UNIXTIME(`t_date`) ) as `day`,
  COUNT(*) as `summ_open`
FROM `table`
WHERE
  `t_status` = 0 AND
  MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME(`t_date`) ) = MONTH( now() )
GROUP BY `day`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `recurcive`
SELECT * FROM `simple`;

SELECT
  `simple`.`day`,
  SUM( `recurcive`.`summ_open` ) as `summ_open`
FROM `simple`, `recurcive`
WHERE `simple`.`day` >= `recurcive`.`day`
GROUP BY `day`;
```

Либо так:

```
SELECT
  `simple`.`day`,
  SUM( `recurcive`.`summ_open` ) as `sum_open`
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DAY( FROM_UNIXTIME(`t_date`) ) as `day`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE
      `t_status` = 0 AND
      MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME(`t_date`) ) = MONTH( now() )
    GROUP BY `t_date`
  ) AS `simple`
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
       DAY( FROM_UNIXTIME(`t_date`) ) as `day`,
      COUNT(*) as `summ`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE
      `t_status` = 0 AND
      MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME(`t_date`) ) = MONTH( now() )
    GROUP BY `day`;
  ) AS `recurcive`
ON `simple`.`day` <= `recurcive`.`day`
GROUP BY `day`
```